# Why is sed not replacing this newline character?

Tags: bash, sed

I'm using sed in a Bash shell on Ubuntu to replace text in some files. Here is the text I have:

```
 BLah </V>
<N> Blah
```

Here is what I want to convert it to:

```
Blah" = "Blah
```

Here is the sed command I am using on it:

```
sed -i 's@ </V>\n<N> @" = "@g'
```

All my other `sed` commands are working except this one. This is the only search and replace situation where there is a newline character involved. The problem seems to be that `\n` isn't matching the new line character like I thought it should.

Where is my script going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is that `sed` processes the text line by line. It doesn't have both line in its buffer (called *pattern space*) simultaneously. You can fix it by tweaking the script:

```
sed 'N;s@ </V>\n<N> @" = "@g'
```

From `man sed`:

```
   n N    Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space.
```

This is what `N` does: appends the next line to the pattern space. Then the substitution works.

Example:

```
$ sed 'N;s@ </V>\n<N> @" = "@g' <<<' BLah </V>
<N> Blah'
 BLah" = "Blah
```

This however will have a 50% chance of not working, depending on whether the pattern starts on an even or odd line in the input. To get around this, you can modify the script like this:

```
sed 'N;s@ </V>\n<N> @" = "@g;P;D'
```

Comment: Probably just a typo, but I think you need the `-i` in `sed 'N;s@ </V>\n<N> @" = "@g'` to make it `sed -i 'N;s@ </V>\n<N> @" = "@g'`, otherwise it doesn't actually execute the change. Other than that, though, worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: @DaveMG I personally only put `-i` in the last moment and never use it for testing; and there's always a possibility that my answer breaks something so I tend to omit the `-i` just in case :)

Comment: `sed '/<\/V>/{N; s@ </V>\n<N> @" = "@g}'`

Comment: @aragaer That's also a good option. `g` is not needed, though.

Answer (score 3):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for any other text processing just use awk:

```
$ cat file
Blah </V>
<N> Blah

$ awk -v RS= 'sub(/ <\/V>\n<N> /,"\" = \"")' file
Blah" = "Blah
```

None of this hold pattern, transporter buffer in subspace or whatever stuff required - just set your Record Separator to something other than a newline and treat your multi-line string just like any other string.